# Haproxy rules(set-header) not working and it's not changing base url of request

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, http-headers, web-applications

I am trying to integrate cloud foundry adminui application. Url which I access
is https://myexample.com/adminui/

It works as follows:

```
 Request 
     https://myexample.com/adminui/    

 Response
     http://uaa.devtest7.io/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=admin_ui_client&redirect_uri=https://admin.devtest7.io/login
```

The above is response is correct but sometimes I get response where redirect url is using internet host name.

```
http://uaa.devtest7.io/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=admin_ui_client&redirect_uri=https://myexample.com/login
```

I am modifying that in haproxy rule as follows. It works like a charm. But in one of the installation it is giving this problem.

```
backend bk_adminui
    mode http
    http-request set-header Host admin.devtest7.io
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)adminui[/]?(.*)     \1\2
```

Code ruby server app

```
def local_redirect_uri(request)
      "#{request.base_url}/login"
    end
```

App uses "#{request.base_url}/login to create redirect uri.sometime it works fine but other time it is not.I am  modifying Host name in haproxy acl.
Do I need to change any other field also? Do base_url and Host is same.

Any suggestions?

UPDATED

I was checking tcpdump of my server app i found this

```
Host: admin.devtest7.io
X-Forwarded-Host: myexample.com
```

Is this X-Forwarded-Host is translating in base_url  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]
```

The above line worked for me.